# Multi send and multi receive on networkstream at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, networkstream

I'm working on an application (Server_Client) that sends and receives messages and upload files and many..

Uploading file : is sending the file parted to the server.

**Main problem**: when a client sends message while uploading a file the server will read the message after the file is finished.

How can I send messages while uploading the file, even if I used threads the problem remains.

Is there something I'm missing and how to implement such a thing?

Comment: You haven't shown any code or given much detail about your implementation. But what you're asking is how to have two concurrent data streams, one for the file transfer and one for messaging. To do that you either need two sockets, or a network protocol that allows multiplexing.

Comment: that exactly what i'm asking

Comment: Every client should have two sockets and the server should have also two sockets for every client?

Answer (score 0):

There is a commonly occurring problem with a simple multi-thread solution.

1. Keep **a pool of worker thread** that will work to serve the incoming requests;
2. Using one dedicated **listener thread, listen to the incoming requests**;
3. When a request is received, **fetch a worker thread and task it with handling the upload** of the data;
4. The dedicated **listener thread will go back to listening** on the same socket.

This way, the next message will be listened to immediately, instead of at the end of the upload of the file from the previous request.

Comment: The thread that will handle the upload will also read the message in between the file if i'm using the same socket i guess

Comment: @yazan: There will be only one thread to listen. As soon as it gets the request, it assigns a worker thread to take care of the upload and goes back to listening to requests on the same socket.